# Anonymous function with goroutines

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the difference between calling goroutine with/without anonymous function.
When I try below code with anonymous function it works.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
      fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }() 
    go send(1, ch)      

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Below code without a anonymous function fails with deadlock.

```
go fmt.Println(<-ch) //fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

The code is available [here](https://play.golang.org/p/QFKIlcrTTCV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)
>
> For an operand ch of channel type, the value of the receive operation
>   <-ch is the value received from the channel ch. The channel direction
>   must permit receive operations, and the type of the receive operation
>   is the element type of the channel. The expression blocks until a
>   value is available.

---

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go fmt.Println(<-ch)
    ch <- 1
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/K3_V92NRWvY

Output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    // At prog.go: line 7: (<-ch)
```

---

`fmt.Println(<-ch)` evaluates its arguments, a receive on `ch`. There is no send pending for `ch`. `fmt.Println(<-ch)` blocks until a value is available, which never happens, it never gets to `ch <- 1`.

---

It is equivalent to:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    arg := <-ch
    go fmt.Println(arg)
    ch <- 1
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/1wyVTe-8tyB

Output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    // At prog.go: line 7: arg := <-ch
```

Comment: Thanks @peterso. `go fmt.Println(<-ch)` This statement means, evaluate `fmt.Println(<-ch)` then execute the result in separate thread?

Comment: @Sabarish: Since it's stuck on evaluating `<-ch`, the argument to `fmt.Println(<-ch)`, it never gets to execute the goroutine.